Call of Dragons log on Android using PC account
How to login to 'Call of dragons' on Android using the same account used on Windows PC?

What's the problem? Can't you use the same email?

I start the game, and there is no option to put a email. I think the email connected to phone with the Android  was used. I can't change it, or I  do not see how to do it.
